# ServiceStack Razor (self-hosted) with embedded images/css

Tags: c#, .net, razor, servicestack

I have a self-hosted WebService/WebApplication using the wonderful Service Stack.

My views are embedded in the DLL, and so are the images.  I am using the `ResourceVirtualPathProvider` code from GitHub.  It finds the index page and layouts correctly, but it can't find the embedded images/css (probably obviously).

How would I go about configuring the Razor plugin to search the path providers.  I've checked in debug mode and the path providers have found all the css and images.  They're just not getting routed.

**EDIT**

I have tried setting the AppHost's `VirtualPathProvider` property to the same provider that I configured the `RazorFormat` plugin with, but to no avail.

**LAST EDIT**

Thanks to Mythz's response, I have now got this working and provide the solution below:

1. Firstly (and I had this before), I used the `Embedded` code from [GitHub](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Plugins.Embedded/VirtualDirectory) to create resource virtual path providers, directories, and files.
2. Implemented a VirtualFileHandler:

   ```
   public sealed class VirtualFileHandler : IHttpHandler, IServiceStackHttpHandler
   {
   private IVirtualFile _file;


   /// <summary>
   /// Constructor
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="file">File to serve up</param>
   public VirtualFileHandler(IVirtualFile file)
   {
       _file = file.ThrowIfDefault("file");
   }   // eo ctor


   public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }


   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   {
       ProcessRequest(new HttpRequestWrapper(null, context.Request),
                      new HttpResponseWrapper(context.Response),
                      null);
   }   // eo ProcessRequest

   public void ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest request, IHttpResponse response, string operationName)
   {
       try
       {
           response.ContentType = ALHEnvironment.GetMimeType(_file.Extension);
           using (Stream reader = _file.OpenRead())
           {
               byte[] data = reader.ReadFully();
               response.SetContentLength(data.Length);
               response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
               response.OutputStream.Flush();
           }
       }
       catch (System.Net.HttpListenerException ex)
       {
           //Error: 1229 is "An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection"
           //This exception occures when http stream is terminated by the web browser.
           if (ex.ErrorCode == 1229)
               return;
           throw;
       }
   }   // eo ProcessRequest
   }   // eo class VirtualFileHandler
   ```
3. Configured everything in my configuration function (the fact it is static is unique to my scenario, but it's effectively called from the regular AppHost's `Configure` function)

   ```
   protected static void Configure(WebHostConfiguration config)
   {
       _pathProvider = new MultiVirtualPathProvider(config.AppHost,
                                                    new ResourceVirtualPathProvider(config.AppHost, WebServiceContextBase.Instance.GetType()),
                                                    new ResourceVirtualPathProvider(config.AppHost, typeof(ResourceVirtualPathProvider)));
       config.Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat()
       {
           EnableLiveReload = false,
           VirtualPathProvider = _pathProvider
       });


       /*
        * We need to be able to locate other embedded resources other than views, such as CSS, javascript files,
        * and images.  To do this, we implement a CatchAllHandler and locate the resource ourselves
        */
       config.AppHost.CatchAllHandlers.Add((httpMethod, pathInfo, filePath) =>
       {
           IVirtualFile file = _pathProvider.GetFile(pathInfo);
           if (file == null)
               return null;

           return new VirtualFileHandler(file);
       });
   }   // eo Configure
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the self-hosted version of [RazorRockstars](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/tree/master/src/RazorRockstars.SelfHost)?

It's not the RazorFormat that needs to know about static files, they're just handled by ServiceStack itself.

You need to set the **Build Action** of each of the static files to **Copy if newer** so they're copied to the `bin/` directory so ServiceStack can find them as it's the base directory where the self-hosted version of ServiceStack is hosted from.

Comment: Hi Mythz, I want to resolve them as embedded resources, not as static files.  The views (both the main index and layout) are resolved perfectly just not the embedded images/css - which is my preference in this scenario :)

Comment: That feature is part of an [EmbeddedFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Plugins.Embedded), which you will need to compile from source to use. Note: You can use it now, but it's not an official part of ServiceStack as its something we intend to reserve for a commercial feature in future.

Comment: I took the code that was given and I have provided the `ResourcePathProvider` classes twice (as I use the `MultiPathProvider`.  ServiceStack finds both the index.cshtml in my main DLL, and the shared layout in the dependent DLL, but not the images...  Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: The static file handler doesn't use the virtual path provider, so you'd have to handle it yourself by registering your own custom `IAppHost.CatchAllHandlers`.

Comment: @Moo-Juice just register a CatchAllHandler in your AppHost and debug the callback, then use that to look into the ResourcePathProvider - you want to return a IHttpHandler that does the work you need. The [MarkdownFormat](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Formats/MarkdownFormat.cs#L126) and [RazorFormat](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Razor/Managers/RazorPageResolver.cs#L44) both have examples of registering and using a CatchAllHandler.

Comment: thanks for your responses.  Will be testing this in the morning and will let you know how it goes.