# Getting a HttpCompileException in ServiceStack Razor view (Self hosted)

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, razor-2

**ASSEMBLY 1**

This is my project structure (I serve up content from embedded resources):

```
Common_Assembly.dll
    Css
        Common.css
    Views
        Shared
            _Layout.cshtml
```

This also has a class called Model.cs, which is essentially just:

```
public class Model
{
     public string Title {get; set; }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@model MyNameSpace.Model
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" href="css/common.css"></script>
        <title>@Model.Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody
    </body>
</html>
```

**ASSEMBLY 2**

I then have a second assembly (which references the one above) and is the one that actually hosts the web-service:

```
Concrete_Assembly.dll
    Views
        Index.cshtml
```

This has a class called `IndexResponse` that derives from `Model` in the other assembly.

```
public class IndexResponse : Model
{ 
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@Model MyOtherNameSpace.IndexResponse
<p>Test</p>
```

Now, the problem.  If I remove the `@Model` line, everything works correctly and I see my index page within the layout page of the other DLL ([I use a custom VirtualPathProvider to locate resources across multiple Dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475547/servicestack-razor-self-hosted-with-embedded-images-css)).  However, if I try and use the `IndexResponse` as a model in the index page, I get a `HttpCompileException`.  As it is thrown by an external component I do not actually know what the exception message is (I use service stack binaries).

At first I wondered if it was because the model class was different from the layout's class (even though it derives from it).  To test that theory I created a `TestModel` class that derives from `Model` (placed IN the common assembly), and used that - it worked fine.

This leads me to believe it is because the `IndexResponse` is in the secondary assembly - but can't be sure because I can't see the error.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

For completeness, here is the actual WebService method.  I do not believe anything is wrong here as it worked fine when I did my other tests (using `TestModel` instead).

```
    public IndexResponse Any(Index index)
    {
        return new IndexResponse() { Title = "Test Title" };
    }   // eo Any
```

**EDIT 2**

Apologies for all the edits.  Furthermore, is there anyway I can get hold of this exception or handle it so I can have a look at the error?  It would be nice to catch this and display it - otherwise developing these pages as embedded resources is going to be like pulling teeth :)

**EDIT 3**

After following some suggestions from Mythz, and adding the correct namespaces in to the Razornamespaces configuration, I have finally gotten hold over the error that it is throwing:

`+      $exception  {"(0): error CS1704: An assembly with the same simple name 'Concrete_Assembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null has already been imported. Try removing one of the references or sign them to enable side-by-side."}   System.Exception {System.Web.HttpCompileException}`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already you should add any assemblies you're using to your `app.config`, e.g:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, 
  Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="ServiceStack.Html" />
    <add namespace="ServiceStack.Razor" />
    <add namespace="ServiceStack.Text" />
    <add namespace="ServiceStack.OrmLite" />
    <add namespace="Concrete_Assembly" />
    <add namespace="Common_Assembly" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Also disable ASP.NET webpages:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

See the [RazorRockstars Self Host app.config](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/blob/master/src/RazorRockstars.SelfHost/app.config) for a reference.

Comment: Is there any way to set these programatically and not via an app.config?

Comment: Yeah you can add them to `Config.RazorNamespaces` but the VS.NET design-time Razor support (i.e. intelli-sense) looks in the web.config configuration.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have Web.configs in my Dlls for the intellisense support but in my scenario, app.configs aren't something I desire.  Trying the programmatic approach as we speak.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I don't appear to have a `RazorNamespaces` as a `Config` property?

Comment: When you see `Config` we always mean on `EndpointHostConfig `where all of ServiceStack's configuration is. Here's [Config.RazorNamespaces](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/EndpointHostConfig.cs#L211)

Comment: Yup, that's what I thought you meant - but it's not a property here, for some bizarre reason...

Comment: oh yeah I forgot to say it's static :)

Comment: Hi Mythz.  I have implemented it, but getting a HttpCompileException in a different place (even if I remove it)..  Is there any way to find out what this compilation error is, or display it somehow?

Comment: I have made an edit as this is the error that's currently occurring in the razor compilation.

Comment: Markthing is as correct as I believe my new issue to be unrelated to this question and it's about how my application initializes and shadows the DLLs in a temporary directory.  Thanks again for the help and if you can let me know how I can catch that exception, that would be great! :)